# How do I set the background color in swfObject?

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am using swfobject to display some Flash content (please don't tell Steve Jobs) and I need to set the background color of the swfobject content to black so it blends nicely with the black page it is on.

I tried using the following code but it didn't change anything:

```
<object id="flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="900" height="600" bgcolor="#000">
```

What is the correct way to set the background color to #000000?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just set the background color when exporting?

Comment: This is not the Flash background. That is black. I am referring to the swfobject background color which defaults to white. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some help over at the swfobject group on google.

The key is to add this to both sections of the object code and it solved the problem:

```
<param name="bgcolor" value="000000" />
```

Comment: note: black doesn't work here - must use 000000 (at least not on IE9)

Comment: don't want to post a separate question as the problem is the same here, http://lug.nitk.info/lug_nitk/index.php?title=Clippy I want the copy button to display a white background (shows blue in ie)

Comment: I used `ffffff` and the loading background is still blank: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476444/how-to-embed-an-avi-file-in-a-asp-net-page?noredirect=1#comment47113715_29476444

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the *flash background* colour then you have to use the bgcolor setting in embedding, or add it to swfObject with the 6th value ([see here](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/)). if you are using a transparent flash etc then the colour is defined by your html/CSS content. have a check of your `background` or `background-color` settings for the div you are embedding it into.